# Android - Set individual stroke of sides of a shape in layerlist programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

This is my shape xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/comp_background" android:top="0px" android:right="0px" android:left="-5px">
<shape>
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="100px"
        android:topRightRadius="100px"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/OptionNotSelected" />
    <stroke android:width="5px" android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

And this is the output i get(**Correct output**)
[image]

Notice that the stroke on the left side is missing.
I want to this programmatically. The code i have tried is this

```
int cornerRadius=50;
float[] med_corners=new float[]{cornerRadius,cornerRadius,0,0,0,0,cornerRadius,cornerRadius};

LayerDrawable layers1 = (LayerDrawable)ContextCompat.getDrawable(context,R.drawable.medicine_btn_background);
GradientDrawable shape1= (GradientDrawable)(layers1.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.med_background));
shape1.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.OptionNotSelected));
shape1.setStroke(5,ContextCompat.getColor(context,android.R.color.black));
shape1.setCornerRadii(med_corners);
btn_medicine.setBackground(shape1);
btn_medicine.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context,R.color.OptionSelected));
```

And this is the output i get
[image: IMAGE2]
Here i get the left border. **I don't want that**. I have placed two buttons side by side, and when clicking on these button i am switching between the backgrounds of these buttons. When i tried the **setBackgroundResource()** method i lose the rounded corners. The code i have given above helps to retain the rounded corners but recreates the left border. Any way to achieve this....?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: you said you losing corner radius can you please add your where you apply this layer list because background resource should work @AkhilSoman

Comment: Can you post your `medicine_btn_background.xml` file?